# JAVA - LDAP Password with special character not working

Tags: java, ldap

I'm trying to create a login screen on my system, where it queries in an Active Directory, but when the user's password has some special character like @ and *, it does not validate.

Do I need to encrypt the password to work? How can I do it?

I am getting the user password through a JPasswordField, using getPassword ().

```
    boolean valid_login = false;
    String password = new String(pwd.getPassword());

    try {

        LdapContext ctx = null;
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();

        try {

            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "Simple");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://ldap:389/");

            ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
            valid_login = true;
            ctx.close();

        } catch (NamingException nex) {
            valid_login = false;
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        valid_login = false;            
    }

    return valid_login;

}
```

Comment: What does the value from  String password = new String(pwd.getPassword()) look like? 
Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask