# Password with special character such as "pàssword" not working in tomcat-users.xml

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I have login problems with a JSF application running locally on Tomcat

I've got a j_security login form that looks roughly like that

```java
<form id="loginForm" method="post" action="j_security_check" >
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
        <h:inputText id="j_username" required="true" label="username" />
        <h:inputSecret id="j_password" required="true" label="password" />
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</form>
```

I've got this in my `web.xml`

```xml
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.xhtml?error=1</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

I'm logging in using my users defined in `tomcat-users.xml`, but it doesn't work with special characters

I added a filter to my `web.xml`

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And I made sure that my connector has URIEncoding in  `server.xml`

```xml
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       connectionTimeout="20000"
       redirectPort="8443"
       URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Related questions:

- [java ldap password with special character not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56775157/java-ldap-password-with-special-character-not-working)
- [how to debug j-security check problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64414978/how-to-debug-j-security-check-problems)

My problems are twofold

1. It doesn't work with special characters (ex: pàssword)
2. I do not know how I can check what password is being sent, is there a way I can log that or intercept it with a debugger or something?

Any help appreciated

Comment: @BalusC that's locally, when the app is deployed the passwords are fetched from active directory

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I hope that it will help someone (I got the same issue to day)

To support special characters, you need to change the encoding to UTF-8 (default is latin1)

I've fixed it by changing the encoding `characterEncoding="UTF-8"`  to UTF-8 in the context.xml file.

```xml
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator" charset="UTF-8"/>
```